# Writing to a new file with conditions

Tags: java

I'm trying to write to a new file as well as printing to screen. The code below is printing to screen OK, but how do I effectively write the contents to a new file?

```
public static void allBBC(ArrayList<TvProgramme> programmes) {
    for (TvProgramme prg : programmes) {
        if (prg.getBroadcaster().equals("BBC")) {
            System.out.println(prg.getProgrammeName());
        }
        
        File file2 = new File ("BBCProgrammes");
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file2);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Define _effectively_. What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: i dont know how to complete the code successfully. I have opened the writer etc but havent written to file yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void allBBC(ArrayList<TvProgramme> programmes) {
        
    File file2 = new File ("BBCProgrammes");

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file2);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for (TvProgramme prg : programmes) {
            if (prg.getBroadcaster().equals("BBC")) {
                System.out.println(prg.getProgrammeName());
            }            

            bw.write(prg.getProgrammName());
            bw.newLine() // if you need a new line, otherwise everything will be in one line
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The file should be created before the loop, otherwise you would open it with every loop.

`write()` will write the information into the cache.

`flush()` will write the written information from cache to the file. You should not flush every single line, except if it is really needed.

Comment: You will have to manually append the line separator (\n) to the string to be written when using a Writer.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thanks for telling me :)